# Twiddle connecting to remote jboss for JMX based operation

Tags: jboss

We have a couple of jboss instances running on different machines. We needed a script to invoke a JMX console operation using twiddle utility available with JBoss.

For localhost the command is working fine but when we try to access the remote via:

```
twiddle.sh -s <servername>:<http port> -uadmin -p<password> serverinfo -c
```

but for remote servers we are facing following exception:

```
05:25:34,205 ERROR [Twiddle] Exec failed
org.jboss.util.NestedRuntimeException: - nested throwable: (javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.rmi.NoSuchObjectException: no such object in table])
at org.jboss.console.twiddle.Twiddle$1.getServer(Twiddle.java:144)
    at org.jboss.console.twiddle.command.MBeanServerCommand.getMBeanServer(MBeanServerCommand.java:59)
    at org.jboss.console.twiddle.command.MBeanServerCommand.queryMBeans(MBeanServerCommand.java:66)
    at org.jboss.console.twiddle.command.InvokeCommand.execute(InvokeCommand.java:274)
    at org.jboss.console.twiddle.Twiddle.main(Twiddle.java:306)
Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.rmi.NoSuchObjectException: no such object in table]
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:780)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:627)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:351)
    at org.jboss.console.twiddle.Twiddle.createMBeanServerConnection(Twiddle.java:251)
    at org.jboss.console.twiddle.Twiddle.connect(Twiddle.java:269)
    at org.jboss.console.twiddle.Twiddle.access$300(Twiddle.java:63)
    at org.jboss.console.twiddle.Twiddle$1.getServer(Twiddle.java:140)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.rmi.NoSuchObjectException: no such object in table
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:247)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:223)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:126)
    at org.jnp.server.NamingServer_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:675)
    ... 10 more
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We weren't able to find a solution for this and finally managed to do so using SSH only.